# Unable to handle request-promise-json error in hystrix module

Tags: node.js, error-handling, promise, hystrix

I am new to node js,i have to implement hystrix resilience library in node js for my project but i am stuck at one point.
Problem i am facing is that whenever i am sending error codes(4xx,5xx) from my server app i am not able to handle them using promise.
I am pasting the code for my **app.js** and **server.js** files.Although the project has several other files but those are for starting all the process but the only issue is in app.js.

Please help me how to efficiently handle the rejected promise error so that i dont get undefined for res,body in isErrorHandler method of **app.js**.

I will also add the console data.

app.js

```
var express = require('express'), Promise = require('q'), request = require('request'), getRandomInt = require('./random_int'), http = require('request-promise-json'), _ = require("lodash"), hystrixStream = require('../../lib/http/HystrixSSEStream'), CommandsFactory = require("../../lib/command/CommandFactory");

var makeRequest = function(options) {
    var req = _.assign(options);

    return http.request(req);
};


function hystrixStreamResponse(request, response) {
    response.append('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8');
    response.append('Cache-Control',
            'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    response.append('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    return hystrixStream.toObservable().subscribe(function onNext(sseData) {
        response.write('data: ' + sseData + '\n\n');
    }, function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }, function onComplete() {
        return response.end();
    });
}

// called from index.js when process.env.app is set
module.exports = function(port) {
    var app = express(), cbs = [], commands = [], reqs = 0;
    var isErrorHandler = function(error, res, body) {

        console.log("Entred error handler");
        console.log("error :" + error);
        console.log("res:" + res);
        console.log("body :" + body);

        if (res.statusCode == 503) {
            console.log("Entred 503 loop");
            var unavailableError = new Error();
            unavailableError.name = " Service Unavailable Error..";
            return unavailableError;
        }

        if (res.statusCode === 404) {
            console.log("Entred 404 loop");
            var notFoundError = new Error();
            notFoundError.name = " Avoided 404..";
            return notFoundError;
        }

        if (error) {
            console.log("Entred default error");
            return error;
        }

        return null;
    };

    // here we are configuring all external communication points within a
    // command
    // also starting point
    this.configure = function(config) {

        config.services.forEach(function(service) {
            var serviceCommand = CommandsFactory.getOrCreate(
                    "Service on port :" + service.port + ":" + port)
                    .circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage(
                            service.errorThreshold).timeout(service.timeout)
                    .run(makeRequest).circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold(
                            service.concurrency)
                    .circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds(service.timeout)
                    .statisticalWindowLength(10000)
                    .statisticalWindowNumberOfBuckets(10).errorHandler(
                            isErrorHandler).build();
            serviceCommand.service = service;
            commands.push(serviceCommand);
        });
    };

    // this is called from stats.js for hystrix Stream Response
    app.get('/api/hystrix.stream', hystrixStreamResponse);




    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
        var promises = [];
        commands.forEach(function(command) {
            var n = getRandomInt(1, command.service.calls);
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                var url = "http://127.0.0.1:3003";
                promises.push(command.execute(url).fail(function(error,response,body) {
                    console.log("Entered fail error:"+error);
                    console.log("Entered fail response:"+response);
                    console.log("Entered fail body:"+body); 
                     //res.send(reason , res, body);
                })
                );
            }
        });

        Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
           results.forEach(function(result) {
               res.send(results.join("\n"));
               res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
               reqs++;
           });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            reqs++;
            res.send("Error: " + error);
        });
    });

    // the app.start() function is called from index.js file..
    this.start = function() {
        // port value is passed from index.js
        process.title = 'node (app:' + port + ')';

        app.listen(port, function() {
            // start variable represents when the app
            // started listening on a particular port
            var start = Date.now();
            console.log("[%d] APP Listening on %d,%d", process.pid, port,
                    process.title);

            // keeps calling this function after ever 1 second
            // reqs is a counter which keeps incrementing after every
            setInterval(function() {
                var elapsed = (Date.now() - start) / 1000;
                var rps = elapsed ? reqs / elapsed : 0;
                console.log("App req/s: " + rps + " : " + port);
            }, 1000);

        });
    };

};
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express'), getRandomInt = require('./random_int');

module.exports = function(port) {
    var app = express(), reqs = 0, sickPercentage = 20, maxSetSickTimeout = 5, sick = false, maintenancePercentage = 5, maxSetMaintenanceTimeout = 15, maintenance = false;

    function setSick() {
        sick = getRandomInt(0, 100) <= sickPercentage;// if smaller or equal
        // to 20 then make it
        // true..
        console.log("SERVICE: ", port, "sick", sick);
        setTimeout(setSick, 1000 * getRandomInt(0, maxSetSickTimeout));//5 is max sick timeout
    }

    function setMaintenance() {
        // if smaller or equal to 5 then make it true..else false
        maintenance = getRandomInt(0, 100) <= maintenancePercentage;

        console.log("SERVICE: ", port, "maintenance", maintenance);
        setTimeout(setMaintenance, 1000 * getRandomInt(0,maxSetMaintenanceTimeout));//5 is maxSetMaintenanceTimeout
    }

    //setSick();
    //setMaintenance();

    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
        reqs++;

        /*if (maintenance) {
            res.status(503).send("Temporaly Unavailable");
            return;
        }*/

        /*var ms;

        if (sick) {
            ms = getRandomInt(0, 10 * parseInt(req.params.ms));
        } else {
            ms = getRandomInt(0, parseInt(req.params.ms));
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            res.send("OK: slept " + ms + " ms");
        }, ms);*/

        (reqs % 2) == 0 ? res.status(200).send('wooohhh loving it..') :res.status(404).send("Kindly Browse more...........");
        //res.status(200).send("All fine here");
        return;

    });

    this.start = function() {
        process.title = 'node (service:' + port + ')';
        app.listen(port, function() {
            var start = Date.now();
            console.log("[%d] SERVICE Listening on %d", process.pid, port);
            setInterval(function() {
                var elapsed = (Date.now() - start) / 1000;
                var rps = elapsed ? reqs / elapsed : 0; //rps=request processed per second
                console.log("Service req/s: " + rps+" : "+ port);//here they are printing requests processed per second
                process.send({
                    rps : rps
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    };
};

/*

module.exports = function(port) {
    var app = express(), reqs = 0, sickPercentage = 20, maxSetSickTimeout = 5, sick = false, maintenancePercentage = 5, maxSetMaintenanceTimeout = 15, maintenance = false;

    function setSick() {
        sick = getRandomInt(0, 100) <= sickPercentage;// if smaller or equal
        // to 20 then make it
        // true..
        console.log("SERVICE: ", port, "sick", sick);
        setTimeout(setSick, 1000 * getRandomInt(0, maxSetSickTimeout));//5 is max sick timeout
    }

    function setMaintenance() {
        // if smaller or equal to 5 then make it true..else false
        maintenance = getRandomInt(0, 100) <= maintenancePercentage;

        console.log("SERVICE: ", port, "maintenance", maintenance);
        setTimeout(setMaintenance, 1000 * getRandomInt(0,maxSetMaintenanceTimeout));//5 is maxSetMaintenanceTimeout
    }

    setSick();
    setMaintenance();

    app.get("/random-sleep/:ms", function(req, res) {
        reqs++;

        if (maintenance) {
            res.status(503).send("Temporaly Unavailable");
            return;
        }

        var ms;

        if (sick) {
            ms = getRandomInt(0, 10 * parseInt(req.params.ms));
        } else {
            ms = getRandomInt(0, parseInt(req.params.ms));
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            res.send("OK: slept " + ms + " ms");
        }, ms);
    });

    this.start = function() {
        process.title = 'node (service:' + port + ')';
        app.listen(port, function() {
            var start = Date.now();
            console.log("[%d] SERVICE Listening on %d", process.pid, port);
            setInterval(function() {
                var elapsed = (Date.now() - start) / 1000;
                var rps = elapsed ? reqs / elapsed : 0; //rps=request processed per second
                console.log("Service req/s: " + rps);//here they are printing requests processed per second
                process.send({
                    rps : rps
                });
            }, 1000);
        });
    };
};

*/
```

console output:

```
The web UI will be on http://localhost:3000/
You have 5 seconds to abort...
5...
4...
3...
2...
1...
This will get a bit verbose...
[932] SERVICE Listening on 3003
[5664] APP Listening on 3004,NaN
Service req/s: 0 : 3003
App req/s: 0 : 3004
Service req/s: 0 : 3003
App req/s: 0 : 3004
Service req/s: 0 : 3003
App req/s: 0 : 3004
Service req/s: 0 : 3003
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
App req/s: 0.2485707183693761 : 3004
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Service req/s: 0.5960659646334194 : 3003
App req/s: 0.39840637450199207 : 3004
Service req/s: 0.49677098857426727 : 3003
App req/s: 0.4980906524987548 : 3004
Service req/s: 0.5676979846721544 : 3003
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
App req/s: 0.5692329585883023 : 3004
Service req/s: 0.7457121551081283 : 3003
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
App req/s: 0.6222000995520159 : 3004
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Service req/s: 1.1042402826855124 : 3003
App req/s: 0.6637168141592921 : 3004
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Service req/s: 1.29366106080207 : 3003
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
App req/s: 0.9960159362549802 : 3004
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Service req/s: 1.9009685887571286 : 3003
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
App req/s: 1.4508523757707652 : 3004
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Service req/s: 2.4896265560165975 : 3003
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
Entred error handler
error :StatusCodeError: undefined undefined failed with status code 404
res:undefined
body :undefined
Entered fail error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
Entered fail response:undefined
Entered fail body:undefined
App req/s: 1.8281535648994514 : 3004
Service req/s: 2.6813759289052324 : 3003
App req/s: 1.686987194233571 : 3004
Service req/s: 2.4903941938238225 : 3003
App req/s: 1.566728386269762 : 3004
```

If i am not wrong then the problem is only while handling promises which execute the requests returning 4xx,5xx errors..

Comment: Would have to expect that `isErrorHandler()` doesn't have the correct signature.

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to `errorHandler` isn't passed arbitrary inputs, only the error object. You should be able to get the status code off of the error.